# Connection failed with pg_cron extension

Tags: database, postgresql, scheduling, postgresql-extensions

Need help with pg_cron extension: I'm using it for the first time: it is failing for me with 'connection failed' error. I have followed all https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron mentioned instructions. Can anyone help me with it:
In my case, it is failing with connection failure error. However, in actual db logs I can't see any error. Why does it happening?

[image]

Comment: Your listen_addresses is probably wrong.  Can you connect with `psql -h localhost`?

Comment: @jjanes - yes , I can connect via that

Answer (score 1):

This command help me to resolve the conection failed issue:

```
UPDATE cron.job SET nodename = '';
```